# Problem with either facet_wrap or gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, gganimate

I'm fairly new to coding in R. I am trying to animate my graphs with gganimate. I've been trying to figure this out for a while. Here is the code:

```
ggplot(gapminder, aes(PerCapGDP, PerCapFT, size = PerCapPHE, color=Province)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors)+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE)  +
  scale_size(range = c(2,12))+
  scale_x_log10()+
  facet_wrap(~Province) +  
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'life expectancy') +
  transition_time(Year) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

I get this error when I run this code:

> Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `Province`.
>       * Plot is missing `Province`
>       * Layer 1 is missing `Province`

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't see `Province`, `PerCapGDP`, or `PerCapFT` in the gapminder data

Comment: gapminder has no `Province`.  How did you modify to get this Province. Add your gapminder to the question using `dput(gapminder)` or `dput(head(gapminder)`